# Labels and marker size in Print Layout don't match those on screen

Tags: qgis

I'm new to QGIS but have been flummoxed at almost the first turn.

My map looks great on the screen, but when I move to Print Layout and add a map, all the symbols and labels are much larger and spoil the map. Screengrabs:
[image: screen]

[image: Print Layout]

All the sizes are, I think, in millimetres. I just use the defaults.

It's not practical to manually change sizes for every layer as I'm using the Natural Earth, which has lots of layers.

Is there a way to change symbol and label sizes globally? I've tried changing the paper size, but that doesn't help.

I'm using QGiS 3.10.10-A on a recent Macbook Pro.

Comment: Be sure that the scales in status bar (in QGIS main window) and in `Map Item Properties > Main Properties > Scale` (in Print Layout) have the same value. For example, `1:50000` and `50000`, respectively.

Comment: Thank you very much, but that draws only a part of the map.